# Avoid committing mistakes with tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am not expert with versioning and svn but at work we use tortoisesvn. The problem is sometimes I commit mistake (personnal code) and ... it's bad :)

I wanna know if there is a way to check on commit if some code exists, like if the commit detect the code 'TODO RM', to avoid commit and show an alert.

I see something related to hooks but it seems something should be done on the server side and I can't modify this side.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good habit is to check each file to be committed, and review (diff) the changes before committing.

Not only will this help avoid committing unwanted code, or if you are integrating with an issue tracking system, code which is not related to the issue, you might pick up problems before they are committed.

That being said, if you really wanted to search for keywords before committing, you could use a [client-side pre-commit hook](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html). For example, write a script which searches for your keywords against the output stored from an svn diff of your working copy.

From the TortoiseSVN documentation on hook scripts:

> A hook is defined for a particular working copy path. You only need to specify the top level path; if you perform an operation in a sub-folder, TortoiseSVN will automatically search upwards for a matching path.
>
> Next you must specify the command line to execute, starting with the path to the hook script or executable. This could be a batch file, an executable file or any other file which has a valid windows file association, e.g. a perl script. Note that the script must not be specified using a UNC path as Windows shell execute will not allow such scripts to run due to security restrictions.
>
> The command line includes several parameters which get filled in by TortoiseSVN. The parameters passed depend upon which hook is called. Each hook has its own parameters which are passed in the following order:
>
> Pre-commit
> PATH DEPTH MESSAGEFILE CWD

Comment: Yes I'm usually checking but sometimes I go to fast and ... the mistake happens. I will take a look on the pre-commit hook, thanks !

Comment: By the way, do you have precious links about how to code hook scripts? I didn't find anything...

Comment: The documentation contains good info, I've updated my answer with the relevant section, but you should be able to use a batch file or powershell script, or even a .NET exe using SharpSVN library would work.